# How to write complex values in registry with WIX 3.11?

Tags: .net, wpf, wix, registry

I want to write this value in registry.

How to assign that value like string? Is a better way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(SOLUTION)**

Instead of signs you need to use HTML code.

You will find here: [html codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)